# How to resume the submit request that was blocked by event.preventDefault(); when the function is executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
</script>
    function videomsg() {               
        event.preventDefault();
        alertify.confirm('custom_title', '', 
            function() { 
                /***I want to undo the event.prevent default inside here that stopped my submit request***/ 
            }, 
            function(){ })
            .set({transition:'zoom',message: 'custom_label.'})
            .show();
 }
</script>
```

I want to undo the `event.preventDefault` inside the `alertify.confirm` function that has stopped my submit request for a button. It

Comment: How are you using this?  You can't undo a preventDefault call, so you probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @Devon what should i use instead if i want to pause a submit request and resume  again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatted your code so that it fits better on screen. Also, it looks like you had more to say, but the rest of your question got cut off. e.g. see the "it..." at the end of your question.

Comment: Use  $('form').submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var confirmOpt = true;
> ```
>
> > ```
> > function videomsg() { 
> >     if(confirmOpt){ 
> >     event.preventDefault(); 
> >     alertify.confirm(''custom_title '', function(){ confirmOpt = false; 
> >     $("#form_id").click(); } , function(){ }).set({transition:'zoom',message: 
> >     'custom_message'}).show(); 
> > }
> > ```
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> This is how i fixed my problem, if you get stuck with similar situation try this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you provide only the javascript part of the code I assume that you use a form for submission, say:

```
<form id='frm'>
```

So, I have assigned the *videomsg()* function to a handler in order to be used in jQuery event functions.

Initially a *submit* event is called in *frm* form.

Afterwards, the solution provided, triggers a *submit* event on the form if the user clicks OK in the confirm dialog.

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/oc5sqheL/)

```
var handler = function videomsg() {      
        alert("Submission detected!");
        event.preventDefault();
        alertify.confirm('custom_title', '', 
            function() { 
                /***I want to undo the event.prevent default inside here that stopped my submit request***/ 
                $('#frm').trigger('submit');
            }, 
            function(){ })
            .set({transition:'zoom',message: 'custom_label.'})
            .show();
 }

 $('#frm').submit(handler);
```

*Footnote:*
   *event.preventDefault()* aborts the current event (*submit* in our case), meaning that **it is not resumable**.
However, triggering the event again should do the trick.
Ofcourse, I don't know exactly what is your aim here since you only present a small portion of the overall code.